# Unexpected border on Stack Overflow code sections with IE11

Tags: bug, design, code-block

A code section like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

Often (but not always) is rendered like this (with an unexpected 1 pixel solid line on the left):

[image]

I saw this *strange* behavior only on IE11 on Windows 8.1 (I tried both with Chrome and IE10 on Windows 7 and I never saw it, I don't know about IE11 on Windows 7).

**EDIT** The scroll bar on the bottom is standard Windows 8 scroll bar. It seems line appears only when horizontal scroll bar is present, for example this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

It won't have line but this code will have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    cout << "This is a very long line of text, it won't fit on one single line! Number #" << i << endl;
}
```

It's rendered like this:

[image]

Note that if long line is "alone" (in this case without `{` and `}`) then line won't appear. Moreover sometimes (even for same text) is visible and sometimes not (*randomly* both in preview and in page).

**EDIT 2** This seems to be an IE11 bug, during scrolling that black line appears (few moments) even in horizontal. I didn't understand how this is related to SO's CSS (see comments) and I didn't see it with other sites but I saw sometimes is a *dashed* line and scrolling page it becomes solid again. I would say it's not a problem for SO's developers...

Comment: Sadly, no-repro on IE11 Windows 7.

Comment: Is that the default scrollbar or some sort of AddOn?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby That's a Windows 8 standard scrollbar.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby yes the scrollbar on bottom is default one for Win8, what shouldn't be there is the dark line on the left (and sometimes it's not there).

Comment: Repro'd on IE11 on Win 8.1 Pro and Win 8.1 RT (desktop version of IE). It is fine on the Metro (Windows Store) version of IE.

Comment: @Adriano can you corellate the dark line with the scrollbar appearance? Does the line appear consistently per-post?

Comment: @JanDvorak for what I saw it appears only when horizontal scroll bar is visible. That said even a small change will make it disappear (for example when I added image in my last example the line did disappear from code block BUT it's still visible in preview while editing the question). It may even be a Win81+IE11 problem more than a SO problem but I saw this only on this site.

Comment: @Adriano did you try some inspection in the debugger console?

Comment: @JanDvorak just a look, of course removing _overflow:auto_ from _pre_ will fix it (and h.scroll will disappear too). I didn't see anything "strange" and calculated style seems correct (curiously removing background color will fix it too, is it just an IE rendering problem? I just tried disabling GPU rendering but problem is still there)

Comment: Gotta love IE11